# Semantic Rules in Scala

Tags: scala, pattern-matching, semantics

Here I've written up code from two rules involving handling environments in Scala.
Everything works out perfectly in the code however I'm not too confident in the definitions I've written up to explain what is going on behind the hood. I'm not sure if anyone can review my rules for correctness? I'm not confident in translating semantic rules. For rule two I have an understanding that an invalid variable will results in evaluating an error. It's not clear to me what rule 1 should be defined in.

Rule 1: [image]
Rule 2: [image]

```
sealed trait Environment 
sealed trait Value

case object EmptyEnv extends Environment
case class Extend(x: String, v: Value, sigma: Environment) extends Environment
case class ExtendRec(f: String, x: String, e: Expr, sigma: Environment ) extends Environment
case class ExtendMutualRec2(f1: String, x1: String, e1: Expr, f2: String, x2: String, e2: Expr, sigma: Environment) extends Environment 

/* -- We need to redefine values to accomodate the new representation of environments --*/
case class NumValue(d: Double) extends Value
case class BoolValue(b: Boolean) extends Value
case class Closure(x: String, e: Expr, pi: Environment) extends Value
case object ErrorValue extends Value


/*2. Operators on values */

def valueToNumber(v: Value): Double = v match {
    case NumValue(d) => d
    case _ => throw new IllegalArgumentException(s"Error: Asking me to convert Value: $v to a number")
}

def valueToBoolean(v: Value): Boolean = v match {
    case BoolValue(b) => b
    case _ => throw new IllegalArgumentException(s"Error: Asking me to convert Value: $v to a boolean")
}

def valueToClosure(v: Value): Closure = v match {
    case Closure(x, e, pi) => Closure(x, e, pi)
    case _ =>  throw new IllegalArgumentException(s"Error: Asking me to convert Value: $v to a closure")
}


/*-- Operations on environments --*/

def lookupEnv(sigma: Environment, x: String): Value = sigma match {
    case EmptyEnv => throw new IllegalArgumentException(s"Error could not find string $x in environment")
    case Extend(y, v, _) if y == x => v
    case Extend(_, _, pi) => lookupEnv(pi, x)
    case ExtendRec(f, y, e, pi) => if (x == f) 
                                          Closure(y, e, sigma)
                                   else
                                          lookupEnv(pi, x)
    case ExtendMutualRec2(f1, x1, e1, f2, x2, e2, pi ) => 
    {
        if (x == f1)
            Closure(x1, e1, sigma)
        else if (x == f2)
            Closure(x2, e2, sigma)
        else 
            lookupEnv(pi, x)
    }
}
```

```
case class Seq(e1: Expr, e2: Expr) extends Expr
....
....
case Seq(e1, e2) => {
            val (v1, store1) = evalExpr(e1, env, store)
            val (v2, store2) = evalExpr(e2, env, store1)
            (v2, store2)
            
        }
```

Comment: Your question lacks some context. Probably before mutual recursion you were implemeting ordinary recursion and non-recursive `let`.

Comment: @DmytroMitin Apologies in advance. I didn't want to overload on content figuring what I'm missing is apparent. That is correct. Let was previous

Comment: You didn't provide `Expr` hierarchy. What is the signature of `evalExpr`? You could try to write a test program with mutual recursion in your language (e.g. `isOdd: Num -> Bool`, `isEven: Num -> Bool`) and see whether it's evaluated correctly.

Comment: On the first screenshot `eval` has two parameters (expression and environment), on the second it has three parameters.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3524485/mutually-recursive-evaluator-in-haskell

Comment: Previous question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64349009/updating-an-environment-in-scala

Comment: Did you find answers for your questions?

Answer (score 0):

Regarding rule 1 it seems you should add one more case to your evaluator

```
def evalExpr(e: Expr, env: Environment, store: ???): (Value, ???) = e match {
  //...
  case Seq(e1, e2) =>
    val (v1, store1) = evalExpr(e1, env, store)
    val (v2, store2) = evalExpr(e2, env, store1) // what if v1 = error?
    (v2, store2)

  case LetRec2(f1, x1, e1, f2, x2, e2, env) =>
    evalExpr(e, ExtendMutualRec2(f1, x1, e1, f2, x2, e2, env), store /*???*/)
}
```